# How to replace a string in awk containing a linefeed?

Tags: awk, sed

I want to process a text file using awk to replace "\n1-0" with " 1-0".

**Wrong is:

```
awk '{gsub("\n1-0", " 1-0"); print}' temp.txt >$TARGET
```

How can this be done? Would sed be a better choice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set the record separator to nothing:

```
$ cat file
tbname  id  department
xyz 20  cic
1-0 xyz 21  csp
xyz 22  cpz
abc 25  cis
abc 26  cta
abc 27  tec

$ awk -v RS= '{gsub("\n1-0", " 1-0")}1' file
tbname  id  department
xyz 20  cic 1-0 xyz 21  csp
xyz 22  cpz
abc 25  cis
abc 26  cta
abc 27  tec
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!